# Sorting OQL result set by object parameter in VisualVm

Tags: java, select, heap-memory, visualvm, oql

Have opened a Java heap dump in VisualVm and I'm trying to formulate an OQL query to return all objects of a specific class (se.greger.sven.olof.node.Task) ordered by one of the objects parameters (refid). Have tried variations of the two queries provided below, but I've not succeeded so far.

Try 1

```
select sort(heap.objects('se.greger.sven.olof.node.Task'), 'it.refid')
```

Try 2

```
select sort(se.greger.sven.olof.node.Task, it.refid)
```

Comment: My reference: http://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html#sort

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`select map(sort(heap.objects('se.greger.sven.olof.node.Task'), 'lhs.refid - rhs.refid'), '{ ID: it.refid, obj: it }')`

I expect that `refid` is long  or int.